# Sitemap generator not uploading sitemap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, sitemap

I started playing with a test app trying to upload sitemaps using Amazon S3. I've been following https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator trying to figure out the gem and have only been half successful. A sitemap will generate in the public folder, but not upload to the S3 bucket.

I've added the config/sitemap.rb found in the tutorial above.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'
require 'aws-sdk'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create_index = true
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'https://www.myapp.herokuapp.com'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
 add '/home', :changefreq => 'daily', :priority => 0.9
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new(fog_provider: 'AWS',
                                                                aws_access_key_id: 'KEY',
                                                                aws_secret_access_key: 'SECRET',
                                                                fog_directory: 'DIR',
                                                                fog_region: 'REGION')
```

I type in

```
rails sitemap:refresh
```

in my terminal and it generates the maps. It just doesn't upload them. No errors, no clues as to what didn't happen, nothing. It even tells me that google and bing are successfully pinged.

Of course I can visit my AWS bucket and manually upload these files but that feels...wrong. I've used shrine for images in the past and am used to uploading to a cache. There must be something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your secrets, maybe you don't have the aws account env vars so S3 adapter would never works or policy in your bucket

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did add those into credentials and they are set on Heroku as well. Still nothing.

Comment: @Grasshopper27 try to setting this value SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"

Comment: I’ll give that a shot either tonight or tomorrow depending on how late I get back from work.

Comment: No, no luck there either. I'll get back to this later. For now I'll have to deal with the manual uploading until I get a better grip on this. Thanks again.